# Can't run project prepared for Docker on IIS Express. CreateHostBuilder: DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created new .net core Blazor Server app. It was initially created to work in linux docker container (and I still want to use it in such way). Unfortunately, startup of this container takes too much time. Especially considering that every small change of *.razor file containing UI requires rebuilding entire app in order to appear in web browser.
So, as workaround, I decided to develop my app in "standard way", using "IIS Express" option in Visual Studio, then eventually test it in container before publishing update to production.

Now, the problem is: I cannot start an app. Debugger stops me at this file:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            [...]

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

The error appears in 5th line (`CreateHostBuilder`).

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'C:\root.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\3.1.2\staticwebassets\V4\'

Comment: Is there a minimal demo that reproduces the same issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Suddenly it started working again, I'm not sure how I fixed it. Probably cleaning project, removing cache-related things and rebuilding everything did the trick.

Comment: For me I think it was due to having an old .net 4.5 project as part of the solution. That project had the old arrangement of ".nuget" and "packages" folder, project target etc. Removing all that stuff seemed to help fix it, even though it was in a different project.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your docker project (the one with the docker logo) as your start up project. Then run that. You should be able to right click the project in solution explorer, then click "Set as Startup Project". Then the name of your docker project will appear in the drop down list next to the run button (the green triangle) where you run your projects from. You can click that run button and it should work.

Comment: Man I search a lot for this with no luck. Thanks a lot